# When does org.apache.sling.api.scripting.SlingScriptHelper.getService(Class<ServiceType>) returns null? VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame

Tags: java, service, osgi, aem, sling

According this documentation link:

[apidocs](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/scripting/SlingScriptHelper.html#getServices(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String))

SlingScriptHelper.getService returns null if service is not availibale.

Can you explain conditions when service is unavailble and how to force it to become availible ?

edit:

components view:
[image]

relevant log:

```
22.09.2014 19:13:17.077 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ****** bind method [bindResolverFactory] not found; Component will fail
22.09.2014 19:13:17.078 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ****** Error during instantiation of the implementation object (java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 13
Exception Details:
  Location:
    *******.unbindConfigurator(L********Configurator;)V @5: if_acmpne
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab4 0086 2ba6 0008 2a01 b500 86b1     
) java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 13
Exception Details:
  Location:
    *****.unbindConfigurator(L*****;)V @5: if_acmpne
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab4 0086 2ba6 0008 2a01 b500 86b1
```

Comment: Check the following links which seems to address similar problems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982555/cq5-sling-servlet-with-querybuilder and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259579/how-do-i-add-the-command-xx-usesplitverifier-to-an-osgi-bundle-built-in-crxde-l

Comment: @rakhi4110 looks like this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-3568

Answer (score 0):

I see a few reasons when a service might not be available:

1. The Bundle implementing the service interface isn't deployed
2. The Bundle is deployed but cannot be started (usually some dependency is missing)
3. The Component could not be started because the activate method threw an exception

You can check `1` and `2` in the OSGi Console, for `3` you'll need to check the logs. To fix it, `1` is obvious, install the bundle. For `2` you need to check what dependency can not be resolved, then you need to check if the bundle exporting the dependency is running. For `3` it may be a problem in the code or an invalid configuration or a referenced service isn't availabl, which could again be any of the three reasons.

Comment: 1-2. Bundle in which service was defined - active

Comment: 3 - component unsatisfied

Comment: Then you have to check the logs or even try to debug the activate method to see why it cannot be activated.

Comment: service class have not activate method

Comment: I changed my answer a bit, I accidentally put the solution for 3 into 2 in the initial post. So you'll need to check why it is unsatisfied, which could be a referenced service which isn't available

Comment: all references satisfied: http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2014/09/22/264/834/810b45982d4d65125803a512bb4cf2faec60fb1d.jpg

Comment: I'm running out of ideas, so last resort is to restart the instance and see if the component is happy afterwards.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help( This problem arose after migration from cq 5.5 to cq 5.6.1

Comment: in logs: bindResolverFactory cannot be found (java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 13....bytecode cpmpatibility problem...

Comment: Might be because it was compiled with a lower version of Java and then trying to run it on a higher version. Not exactly sure though.

Comment: I use same java 7 for compiling and executing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a java compatibility issue. Java 7 introduce new validation for the class file. If the method are generated at runtime via bytecode that could cause issue if the bytecode version does not match.

which version of cq are you running? which version of java are you compiling for? you can try compiling with a java 6 target.

Comment: cq 5.6.1. I compile with java 7. I didn't understand this: **you can try compiling with a java 6 target**

Comment: you can specify for which bytecode version you are compiling the code. If the bytecode generator try to match the version of the bytecode it's trying to instrument then it will solve it. If you use maven you need to configure the compiler plugin    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.6</source>
     <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>